# Нормальный ввывод значения из базы данных sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite3, discord.py

Пишу бота дискорд. Когда вывожу пользовательский баланс он выводится таким: Now he has (600,) points!
что бы выводило только 600, а не кортеж, по идее я должен написать так:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT balance FROM members")
print(cursor.fetchall()[4][0])
```

И действительно это работает, но только в консоли Sublime Text. В дискорде же значение все так же выводится кортежем

```
if member.id == ...:
            await ctx.send(f"Balance of {member} was decreased by 100 pts!")
            cursor.execute("UPDATE members SET balance = balance - {} WHERE name = 'Ilya'".format(number))
            connection.commit()
            cursor.execute("SELECT balance FROM members")
            await ctx.send(f"Now he has {cursor.fetchall()[4][0]} points!")
            connection.commit()
```

Вот код вывода в дискорде

Comment: Должно выводить значение, а не кортеж, мб бота не перезапустили или код не обновили?

Comment: Не, только что все сохранил, даже Саблайм закрыл. Перезапустил, все равно выводит кортеж. Самое интересное, что ошибок не выдает

Comment: А покажите в вопросе текущий код, в котором обращение к базе и вывод

Comment: И в `Now he has (600,) points!`? Не должно быть... `cursor.fetchall()` вернет список кортежей, `cursor.fetchall()[4]` вернет 5-й результат. Только если в значении баланса у вас записано не число, а кортеж с числом

Comment: Да, вот: Balance of ... was increased by 100 pts!
Now he has (900,) points!

Comment: может быть как то не так добавлял значения в таблицу?

Comment: я создал список из кортежей, в каждый кортеж поместил имя и баланс. а потом методом executemany добавил все в бд

Comment: А саааамое смешное, что сейчас сделал команду для проверки баланса, и там уже баланс выводится как следует....

Comment: Похоже, такое значение уже было в базе. Мб неправильно положили? Я бы в саму базу посмотрел через какую-нибудь программу, типа SQLiteStudio

Comment: Да я бы тоже посмотрел... не умею пользоваться этим приложением. Пишет что у меня ошибка в базе, не выбран тип базы(sqlite3), выбираю его, не дает сохранить. Не подскажете ,может, как открыть ее, что бы было видно непосредственно столбцы, строки и значения?

Comment: Не знаю, в чем у вас проблема... Сейчас проверил у себя подключения к новой sqlite базе https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmBqO.png и https://i.stack.imgur.com/29rYS.png

Comment: Все, починил, но теперь вижу, что у меня нет таблиц в моей базе данных, судя по приложению. Однако в саблайме обращения к любым данным работают

Comment: Или какая-то фигня с SQLiteStudio, или вас 2 файла базы данных. С одним питон в саблайме работает, с другим то приложение. Проверьте пути, убедитесь что рабочая папка питона в саблайме совпадает с папкой, в которой файл, что открываете из SQLiteStudio

Comment: Да, пути одинаковые. Зашел в sqlitestudio, кликнул на базу данных, нажал 'open file`s directory', привело куда надо